# IE8 whines about Prototype, "'undefined' is null or not an object"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I have an element that is dynamically created with `new Element('div')` and is then faded in, moved, and faded out. In every browser, my code works as expected – every browser but IE.

Internet Explorer complains that `'undefined' is null or not an object` exactly as documented on [Prototype's Lighthouse](https://prototype.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8886/tickets/799).

To get the error, I write, `new Message('Your contact information has been saved');`

The source for my Message class is available at [this gist](http://gist.github.com/210723).

Comment: Are you using the latest Prototype?  1.6.0 does not have proper IE8 support, especially when dealing with creating new elements.

Comment: I'm using Google hosted Prototype 1.6.1.

Comment: global variables? I'm embarrassed, I thought that variables declared as var were global. That sucks. Why the hell is global the default scope?

Comment: Also, that wasn't a particularly polite remark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Undefined is null of not an object” is a very basic error message that can be produced in a huge range of situations (it's JScript's effective equivalent of a null pointer exception). So it's unlikely yours is the same error as mentioned above.

I don't get that error though. I get “Invalid argument”, which seems to be caused by:

```
new Effect.Move(_div, {sync: true, x: '50%', y: 35, mode: 'relative' })
```

If I change the % to a normal integer pixel value it works fine. `x` is [documented](http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/effect-move) as accepting only an integer value not a CSS measurement; the '%' doesn't work for me in other browsers either (acts as 0). I guess you've made this feature up!

As Fabien mentioned, you also need to insert some `var` statements, otherwise you're scribbling over the globals and Message will blow up if you try to create two of them. Plus take care not to leave a trailing `,` in an array literal (due to the commented line), as this confuses IE.

Comment: I think his problem is related to the extra comma after 
new Effect.Fade(_div, {sync: true}),
because of the comment on the next line. I really love the errors thrown by IE...

Comment: To bad it doesn't do my every will. Seriously though, global being the default scope saddens me.

Comment: Yes, default-global is an egregious design error in the JavaScript language, and not the only one. :-(